# Populating ListView from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a ListView populated from a Firebase Database:

This is my code:

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(".../comunidades");

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this.getActivity(),
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);
            mProgress.dismiss();

        }
    };
```

And this is the Firebase console for this database, branch:"comunidades":

[image]

But I am using the same code at another fragment to populate a listview with objects from another branch from the same database, but I get an error.

This is the new code:

```
final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(".../Enclaves");

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this.getActivity(),
            String.class,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);


        }
    };
```

What should I change to get the value for the key "Nombre_enclave" from branch "Enclaves":

[image]

Comment: What's the error? @NewAtFirebase

Comment: Your FirebaseListAdapter can't hold strings. It needs to be objects that map to the model that is stored in Firebase. Objects that have a string field of `Nombre_enclave`

Comment: @NewAtFirebase: I provided an answer below. But for future questions, provide your JSON as text please instead of a screenshot. You can easily get the text by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database Console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable and allows us to easily use it in our comments and answers.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thank for your advice and for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have under `enclaves` is not a list of String+String pairs. Instead it's a list of String+Object pairs, with each object having a Comunidad_enclave, Descripcion_enclave, etc.

The quickest way to make this work is to decide what property you want to show and then override `parseSnapshot()`:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
        this.getActivity(),
        String.class,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        databaseReference
) {
    @Override
    protected String parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.child("Comunidad_enclave").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(model);
    }
};
```

A better way to solve this is to create a class that represents each comunidad. In its simplest form that could look like this:

```
class Comunidad {
    public String Comunidad_enclave;
    public String Descripcion__enclave;
    // TODO: the same for the other properties
}
```

With this class, you can make your adapter of type `Comunidad`:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Comunidad> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Comunidad>(
        this.getActivity(),
        String.class,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        databaseReference
) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Comunidad model, int position) {
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView1.setText(model.Comunidad_enclave);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView2.setText(model.Descripcion_enclave);
    }
};
```

Comment: It works, thank you, but I don´t get how it works. How does the method parseSnapShot make the job?

Comment: When you don't override `parseSnapshot()` the adapter will automatically convert the `DataSnapshot` to the class that you specified in the constructor (in your case a `String`). Since your items are not simple strings in the second case, that conversion will result in nothing. By overriding `parseSnapshot()`, you can control what data is passed into `populateView()`. Check out the code for the adapter, which is surprisingly small. The relevant part is: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java#L118

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I have seen your contributions here at SO and I am learning a lot at them.